# Linux bash parsing URL

Tags: bash, sh

How to parse the url, for example: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe

So that only virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36 remains?

```
TEST_URLS=(
  https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe
  https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4/npp.8.4.4.Installer.x64.exe
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1/libtirpc-1.3.1.tar.bz2
)

for url in "${TEST_URLS[@]}"; do
     without_proto="${url#*:\/\/}"
  without_auth="${without_proto##*@}"
  [[ $without_auth =~ ^([^:\/]+)(:[[:digit:]]+\/|:|\/)?(.*) ]]
  PROJECT_HOST="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  PROJECT_PATH="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

  echo "given: $url"
  echo "  -> host: $PROJECT_HOST path: $PROJECT_PATH"
done
```

Comment: Please do add your tried code as your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you(NOT my downvote btw).

Comment: Please add what you have tried to extract the content.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` to match whether a sub domain is present (no matter how deep) or not.

```
$ sed -E 's~[^/]*//(([^.]*\.)+)?([^.]*\.[a-z]+/[^0-9]*[0-9.]+).*~\3~' <<< "${TEST_URLS[0]}" 
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
```

Or in a loop

```
for url in "${TEST_URLS[@]}"; do
  sed -E 's~[^/]*//(([^.]*\.)+)?([^.]*\.[a-z]+/[^0-9]*[0-9.]+).*~\3~' <<< "$url"
done

virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
```

Comment: For some reason I got it on the second line with /
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
/github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1

Comment: how to output <<< "$url" to variable?

Comment: For some reason if you have domains simple.de, simple.cc, simpe.xxxx and others, the result comes out with a dot at the end:
https://www.simple.re/file-39.zip
simple.re/file-39.
How can I make it work for all types?

Comment: TEST_URLS=(
  https://www.simpledef.de/release/notepad-8.90.zip
  https://www.simple.club/downloads/prog1.exe
  http://www.simple.com/downloads/nasm-ex8.tar
)
for url in "${TEST_URLS[@]}"; do
     echo "${url}"
     new_url=($(sed -E 's~[^/]*//(([^.]*\.)+)?([^.]*\.[a-z]+/[^0-9]*[0-9.]+).*~\3~' <<< "$url"));
    echo "${new_url}"
done
https://www.simpledef.de/release/notepad-8.90.zip
simpledef.de/release/notepad-8.90.
https://www.simple.club/downloads/prog1.exe
simple.club/downloads/prog1.
http://www.simple.com/downloads/nasm-ex8.tar
simple.com/downloads/nasm-ex8.

Comment: download_urls=(
  https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe
  https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4/npp.8.4.4.Installer.x64.exe
https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1/libtirpc-1.3.1.tar.bz2
https://www.nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip
)
My output:
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24. this is dot end.

Comment: @Gersa Does this work `sed -E 's~[^/]*//(([^.]*\.)+)?([^.]*\.[a-z]+/[^0-9]*[^/]*).*~\3~'` ?

Comment: no working...Output end .zip:                                                                                             https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip

Comment: How do you do regular expressions and where do you learn how to do it?

Comment: @Gersa What is the output you expect? I think we are all assuming at this point. There are many resources to learn regular expression, but each language approach to using them may be somewhat different.

Comment: Input:
 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe'
   'https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4/npp.8.4.4.Installer.x64.exe'
    'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1/libtirpc-1.3.1.tar.bz2'
   'https://www.nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip'
Output:

virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples here is an `awk` solution. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/https?:\/\/([^/]*)(\/.*)\//,arr){
  num=split(arr[1],arr1,"/")
  if(num>2){
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++){
      firstVal=(firstVal?firstVal:"") arr1[i]
    }
  }
  else{
    firstVal=arr[1]
  }
  print firstVal arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function here. Using GNU `awk` version of it, where it supports capturing groups getting stored into an array, making use of that functionality here. Using regex `https?:\/\/([^/]*)(\/.*)` could be also written as `^https?:\/\/([^/]*)(\/.*)` where its getting created 2 capturing groups and creating arr also. Then checking if elements are more than 2 then keep last 2 else keep first 2(domain names one), then printing values as per requirement.

Comment: Works better than mine

Comment: @HatLess, Thank you man, yours is COOL actually, will try to add perl also once I get time, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Your code works, but not in the right way.

Comment: @Gersa, kindly do elaborate in which way its NOT working and I will try to help here, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
 Outputs:
download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
www.nssm.cc/release

And you need to:
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
nssm.cc/release

One more thing, the addresses should not be taken from a file but from a variable. Thank you!

Comment: @Gersa, ok sure, that I can fix. But output is coming fine right?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I think so, the output is normal.

Comment: @
RavinderSingh13, How was the writing?

Answer (score 1):

I tought about regex but cut makes this work easy.

```
url=https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe

echo $url | grep -Po '([^\/]*)(?=[0-9\.]*)(.*)\/' | cut -d '/' -f 3-
```

Result

> virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36

Comment: And if, for example, https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4/npp.8.4.4.Installer.x64.exe, it does not work.
How do I make it work for everyone?

Comment: But now you changed the url structure, the previous one has a subdomain. To make it generic only with regex, let me try with those both url

Comment: I made the regex https://regex101.com/r/pfSUwI/1 but I couldn't make it work in bash yet.

Comment: Ok it's done. I did a workaround as the regex was getting to complicated. echo $url | grep -Po '([^\/]*)(?=[0-9\.]*)(.*)\/
' | cut -d '/' -f 3- . PLease run it and let me know if it work to change my answer

Comment: no working of variant.

Comment: there was a extra space when I paste the regex. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am correct in assuming that you need to extract a string of the form...

hostname.tld/dirname

...where tld is the *top-level domain* and dirname is the *path to the file*.

So filtering out any *url scheme* and *subdomains* at the beginning, then also filtering out any *file basename* at the end?
All solutions have assumptions. Assuming one of the original thee letter top level domains ie. .com, .org, .net, .int, .edu, .gov, .mil.

This possible solution uses `sed` with the `-r` option for the regular expressions extension.
It creates two filters and uses them to chop off the ends that you don't want (hopefully).

It also uses a **capture group** in `filter_end`, so as to keep the `/` in the filter.

```
test_urls=(
    'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36/VirtualBox-6.1.36-152435-Win.exe'
    'https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4/npp.8.4.4.Installer.x64.exe'
    'https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1/libtirpc-1.3.1.tar.bz2'
)

for url in ${test_urls[@]}
do
    filter_start=$(
        echo "$url" | \
        sed -r 's/([^.\/][a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,})\/.*//' )

    filter_end=$(
        echo "$url" | \
        sed 's/.*\(\/\)/\1/g' )

    out_string="${url#$filter_start}"
    out_string="${out_string%$filter_end}"

    echo "$out_string"
done
```

Output:

```
virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.36
github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4.4
sourceforge.net/project/libtirpc/libtirpc/1.3.1
```

Comment: If, for example, not .org, .com, but .de, .gltd, .club and others, it doesn't work. Can I fix it and how ?

Comment: It's just that `{3}`.
filter_start will still do it's job using a range, like `{2,}`, which matches two or more tld letters.
`sed -r 's/([^.\/][a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,})\/.*//' `